# Execute Prepared and Batch Statement in SparkSession.SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

How to execute Prepared and Batch Statement against Cassandra in Java using SparkSession.SQL?
I'm using Spark 2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Batching and Prepared Statements happen automatically.

Long answer: SparkSql works through the Spark Cassandra Connector - Cassandra Datasource. The Datasource relation defines how data is read from and written to Cassandra. Under the hood this means any writes via the SparkSql or Dataset api will use all the features that come with the Spark Cassandra Connector.

All writes will be done using prepared statements and Partition key batches. To adjust how the batching is done (or any other write configuration) you can change the parameters listed here

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#write-tuning-parameters

Since SparkSql only communicates through this relation there is no way to use Cassandra specific notions like Batching or Prepared statements.

Comment: I don't have the resources to do one on one support :) But feel free to send emails to the mailing list and I'll see if I have time
https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!forum/spark-connector-user

Comment: Thanks a lot ! this is more than enough

Comment: Another thing, does this mean that I need just to execute the multiple Insert statements each alone then Spark can take care of them or I need to write "Start batch" and group them in one Statement?

Comment: You shouldn't be writing single insert statements in spark sql. You should be transforming other big data objects. Like `SELECT * from X  Where X.a > 5 INSERT INTO Y`

Comment: sorry.. I'm not familiar with this. could you please direct me to a good document ?

Comment: hi Russ..Could you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957655/cassandra-simple-insert-statement-using-spark-sql-fails-with-org-apache-spark-sq ...sorry for posting here about another question.. but I got no response on that question here nor from Spark user mailing list.