# Cassandra Simple Insert Statement using Spark SQL Fails with org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to insert data into Cassandra table with Spark SQL as follows:

```
String query = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_table USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra OPTIONS (table \"my_table\",keyspace \"my_keyspace\", pushdown \"true\")";
                spark.sparkSession.sql(query);
                spark.sparkSession
                                .sql("INSERT INTO my_keyspace.my_table (column0, column1) VALUES ('value0', 'value1');
```

however, it fails with the following exception:
E

```
xception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input 'column0' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'VALUES', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'MAP', 'REDUCE'}(line 1, pos 33)
```

I tried it without the column names and it worked.
My point here is to insert data for some columns, not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark SQL does not use the same syntax as CQL they are different languages. Check HiveQL references for more information.

One warning, doing single row inserts through SparkSql will be very slow. It is made for large multi record (millions) inserts.

Comment: Thanks Russ. I used the HiveQL format and was able to insert into table. However, I still have a problem: if a table has 4 columns and I need to insert data into three of them only (including the keys), how can I do that? currently the following error appears: Cannot insert into table unknown because the number of columns are different: need 4 columns, but query has 3 columns

Comment: You would have to insert a Row Struct I would believe, SparkSQL is really not made for doing this kind of individual inserts....

Comment: Aside comment, Cassandra CQL is a good alternative for my case; in which individual rows need to be inserted\updated. However, you need to have a deep look @ Cassandra batch

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying, batches are available from cql...  Spark SQL is for manipulating data already in another distributed system like hdfs or Cassandra or some other database.

Comment: yes.. I know. What's I'm trying to say is that for individual inserts you may use Cassandra CQL driver directly. However, if you go with CQL and you need sometimes to insert large set of data, then you may consider study batch.

Comment: Batches are actually not a great solution to huge inserts into cassandra except in very particular situations. 

https://www.slideshare.net/BrianHess4/bulk-loading-into-cassandra
For example

Unless you share a partition key there is additional cost with doing batches as well as availability requirements. The SCC for example automatically batches but only on PK unless the user requests otherwise.  Logged batches are additionally more costly.

Comment: That what exactly I discovered lately... thanks Russ